# I want to add text limit in TextView using sytles.xml what should I do

Tags: android, xml, apk

I can't use
**android:maxLines="1"** to add to file **styles.xml** I used the following code
`<item name="android:maxLines">1</item>`
It can't display 1-line text like I want

Comment: Text limit is number of character not max line . Do u want limit number of character in `TextView`?

Comment: No I mean want 'TextView' into 1 line and it's done in styles.xml

Comment: Can you add expected result SS and actual result SS along with some code of style and Textview in which you have applied style so we can trace it easily

Comment: Now it is possible to add android:maxLines="1" it becomes 1 single line however i want to do it in res/values/styles.xml how do i do it i tried it many times with <item n